# Extract numbers from specific lines of a text file starting with strings in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a code where I need to read the data from text files, and extract only specific numbers from it. I have tried numpy loadtxt and genfromtxt, but still struggling to find an answer. Here is an example of a file I need to extract data from:

```
    #
    #Text
    #
    # =============================
    # Text
    # Text
    # Text
    # Text
    # Text
    # =============================
    /gps/ene/type Arb
    /gps/hist/type arb
    /gps/hist/point   9.200000E-04   1.835400E+11
    /gps/hist/point   1.200000E-03   1.577700E+11
    /gps/hist/point   1.600000E-03   1.348800E+11
    /gps/hist/point   2.100000E-03   1.137300E+11
    /gps/hist/point   2.700000E-03   9.759600E+10
    /gps/hist/point   3.500000E-03   8.348800E+10
    /gps/hist/point   4.500000E-03   6.868300E+10
    /gps/hist/point   5.900000E-03   5.317300E+10
    /gps/hist/point   7.700000E-03   3.917900E+10
    /gps/hist/point   1.000000E-02   2.723300E+10
    /gps/hist/point   1.300000E-02   1.762600E+10
    /gps/hist/point   1.700000E-02   1.058500E+10
    /gps/hist/point   3.000000E-02   3.548700E+09
    /gps/hist/point   6.100000E-02   1.274400E+09
    /gps/hist/point   8.900000E-02   5.074400E+08
    /gps/hist/point   1.300000E-01   1.705900E+08
    /gps/hist/point   1.800000E-01   7.722800E+07
    /gps/hist/point   2.700000E-01   2.671600E+07
    /gps/hist/point   4.000000E-01   9.265800E+06
    /gps/hist/point   6.100000E-01   2.225000E+06
    /gps/hist/point   9.100000E-01   6.600100E+05
    /gps/hist/point   1.280000E+00   2.264300E+05
    /gps/hist/point   1.990000E+00   4.632400E+04
    /gps/hist/point   2.440000E+00   1.928300E+04
    /gps/hist/point   3.070000E+00   6.847300E+03
    /gps/hist/point   3.970000E+00   1.584400E+03
    /gps/hist/point   5.200000E+00   0.000000E+00

    #
    #Normalisation
    #
    /control/alias  NORM_FACTOR_SPECTRUM "   2.945935E+17 "
    /control/alias  NORM_FACTOR_ANGULAR "   2.500000E-01 "
```

I need to get only the numbers after the lines starting with "/gps/hist/point", and put them in a 2-d array. Any solution to this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us your code [mre] and ask specific questions. Are you familiar with `str` methods like `startswith()` and `split()`?

Comment: If you know which lines you want by row number you can use `loadtxt` with row skip and max rows (and `usecols`).  But if not you need to read the test with plain old Python line reads and select the desired lines yourself.  You learned about file handing in your into Python reading (or course), didn't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myList = []

lines = [line for line in open('myfile.txt', 'r')]
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('/gps/hist/point'):
        myList.append([line.split()[1], line.split()[2])
```

Comment: Works like a charm!! Thank you so much for the fast answer :)

Comment: Yes, I do! :) It's just a lack of coding skils from my side, but I fully understand the rationale. You read each line in a loop, and if the line starts with "/gps/hist/point" you split it in columns, and then get column 1 and 2 appending those to myList, and ignoring column 0. Correct?

Comment: Yup, you got it.